# [Angular.js + JSF) Can't get element of ArrayList with $index in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsf

I've a Bean with an ArrayList Languages. With languages.getname(index) I can get the name (string) of the language with Bean.Lanuages.get(index).name

I've saved the length -1 (because index starts with 0 and length with 1) of the ArrayList in numberofLanguages.

Now I'm trying to view the name of each language in a multiselectable which is built with a ng-repeat.

Important parts of my script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ui.bootstrap' ]);

app.controller("LanguageCtrl", languageController);

function languageController($scope){{
      $scope.range = function(min, max, step){
        step = step || 1;
        var input = [];
        for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) input.push(i);
        return input;
      };
};
}
```

Important parts of my .htmlx:

```
<div class="panel-group col-md-12" id="accordion" role="tablist"
aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div ng-repeat="n in range(0,#{Bean.numberOfLanguages})">   
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                   data-parent="#accordion" href="#lang-german"
                   aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="lang-german">
                   #{Bean.Languages.get($index).name}
                </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
```

The ng:repeat works fine, I've two languages in my ArrayList and it displays the content two times, but it just shows the name of the first language two times. I've tested #{Bean.Languages.get(1).name, and then the name of the 2nd language is shown.

But I don't want to hardcore it, because there will be much more languages in the future. So how can I get the current language?

Answer (score 0):

$index starts from 0 not one. In your case language one is index 0 and language two index 1

Comment: That's the reason why I've done this:

"I've saved the length -1 (because index starts with 0 and length with 1) of the ArrayList in numberofLanguages."

Comment: And what happens if you hardcode 0 insted of $index

Comment: Then the first language is shown. So that works how it should work, if I just write {{$index}} it works too. Then I first get 0 and then 1, but I don't want numbers, I want the names of the language with that index.